# text-overflow on a multi-line container

Tags: css

I want to signal the user if the text is too long to be displayed in a multi-line container but I can't use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

because it causes the text to overflow in the first-line.

And unfortunately there is no pseude-element selector for the last-line so
What's the solution?

Comment: can you post this on jsfiddle.net? need to see what's happening

Answer (score 0):

add width to the class for example

```
.yourclass{width:300px;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abdulmalik/jMfZF/)